# How to update SeekBar after android rotation?

Tags: android, seekbar, android-mediaplayer

I use [this media player](http://www.hrupin.com/2010/12/15/simple-android-mp3-media-player) but when I rotate the emulator (Ctrl+F11) the startPlayProgressUpdater() doesn't work properly.
How can I update seekbar after rotation?

Answer (score 1):

Save the seekbar position in `onSaveInstanceState()` callback in activity.

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("current_position", seekbarPosition);
    }
```

In `onCreate` of your activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  .......
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    // set seek bar position from `savedInstanceState`
  }
}
```

### Update

Move the notification runnable out of the start method.

```
Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

Then in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method remove all callbacks from the handler.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("current_position", seekbarPosition);
    handler.removeCallbacks(notification);
}
```

Comment: Your code works properly in the first second of rotation but after that, the seek position doesn't follow the mediaplayer!
it seems after rotation, the startPlayProgressUpdater() method doesnt work properly.

Comment: I have updated the answer. remove the callbacks and make `notification` the member.

Comment: after many many effort, I couldn't find the solution. I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the program in this way, solution below.

```
package org.example.java;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, Runnable  {

private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seekBar;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("Player", "got to onCreate()");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initViews();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d("Player", "got to savedInstanceState id not null");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("current_position"));
        seekBar.setProgress(savedInstanceState.getInt("current_position"));
        handler.post(this);
    }
} 

@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onSaveInstanceState()");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("current_position", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of onSaveInstanceState");

}

private void initViews() { 
    Log.d("Player", "got to initViews()");
    buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(this); 

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsong_20_sec);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Log.d("player", "got to End of initViews()");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onClick");

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ButtonPlayStop:
        buttonClick();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of onClick");

}

private void buttonClick() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to buttonClick");
    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(R.string.pause_str);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.d("Player", "got to before startPlayProgressUpdater in buttonClick");
            startPlayProgressUpdater();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            mediaPlayer.pause(); 
        }
    } else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of buttonClick");

}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to startPlayProgressUpdater()");
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    int pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    Log.d("Player", "Current position is " + Integer.toString(pos));
    Log.d("Player", "got to After seekBar.setProgress");
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) { 
        Log.d("Player", "got to before handler.postDelayed");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        Log.d("Player", "got to after handler.postDelayed");

    } else if (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayStop.setText(R.string.play_str);
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of startPlayProgressUpdater()");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onTouch");

    seekChange(v);
    return false;
}

private void seekChange(View v) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to seekChange");

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to run()");

    startPlayProgressUpdater();
    Log.d("Player", "got to after startPlayProgressUpdater in run()");

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.seekTo(0);
}
}
```

## Update

After all I find the solution, but it is very dirty :D

```
package org.example.java;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class Player extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener, OnCompletionListener, Runnable  {

private Button buttonPlayStop;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private SeekBar seekBar;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.d("Player", "got to onCreate()");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initViews();
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Log.d("Player", "got to savedInstanceState id not null");
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(savedInstanceState.getInt("current_position"));
        seekBar.setProgress(savedInstanceState.getInt("current_position"));
        mediaPlayer.start();
        handler.post(this);
    }
} 

@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onSaveInstanceState()");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); 
    outState.putInt("current_position", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of onSaveInstanceState");
    pauseMedia();

}

private void initViews() { 
    Log.d("Player", "got to initViews()");
    buttonPlayStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonPlayStop);
    buttonPlayStop.setOnClickListener(this); 

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.testsong_20_sec);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
    seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    seekBar.setOnTouchListener(this);
    Log.d("player", "got to End of initViews()");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onClick");

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.ButtonPlayStop:
        buttonClick();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of onClick");

}

private void buttonClick() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to buttonClick");
    if (buttonPlayStop.getText() == getString(R.string.play_str)) {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(R.string.pause_str);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.d("Player", "got to before startPlayProgressUpdater in buttonClick");
            startPlayProgressUpdater();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            mediaPlayer.pause(); 
        }
    } else {
        buttonPlayStop.setText(getString(R.string.play_str));
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of buttonClick");

}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to startPlayProgressUpdater()");
    seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
    int pos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    Log.d("Player", "Current position is " + Integer.toString(pos));
    Log.d("Player", "got to After seekBar.setProgress");
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) { 
        Log.d("Player", "got to before handler.postDelayed");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        Log.d("Player", "got to after handler.postDelayed");

    } else if (mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        buttonPlayStop.setText(R.string.play_str);
    }
    Log.d("Player", "got to End of startPlayProgressUpdater()");
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to onTouch");

    seekChange(v);
    return false;
}

private void seekChange(View v) {
    Log.d("Player", "got to seekChange");

    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        SeekBar sb = (SeekBar) v;
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Log.d("Player", "got to run()");

    startPlayProgressUpdater();
    Log.d("Player", "got to after startPlayProgressUpdater in run()");

}

@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.seekTo(0);
}

public void pauseMedia() {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

}

## Update 2:

I have find another way:
[using getLastNonConfigurationInstance()](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/11/07/rotational-forces-part-two/) method.